Add a custom column to WooCommerce admin orders page with HPOS enabled
I want to have a custom column in my WooCommerce admin orders page.
it's about WHO CREATED AN ORDER ( actually I want the author name ). With HPOS in WooCommerce I cant Use the normall codes. beacuse tables of woocommerce has chagned.
function add_wc_order_list_custom_column( $columns ) {
    $new_columns = array();

    foreach ( $columns as $column_name => $column_info ) {
        $new_columns[ $column_name ] = $column_info;

        if ( 'order_status' === $column_name ) {
            $new_columns['custom_order_list_action'] = 'Custom Column';
        }
    }

    return $new_columns;
}

function display_wc_order_list_custom_column_content( $column, $order ) {
    if ( $column == 'custom_order_list_action' ) {
        $author_id = $order->get_customer_id();
        $author = get_userdata( $author_id );
        echo $author ? $author->display_name : 'Unknown Author';
    }
}

Thanks for your help . . .
I've tried so many ways from Ai,forums and etc and I want from Programmers to help me with this problem.

I found thatcode and it works but I want from you guys that change this code and shows authors name not the orders id :                                                                                                                             add_filter( 'manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_columns', 'add_wc_order_list_custom_column', 20 );
add_action( 'manage_woocommerce_page_wc-orders_custom_column', 'display_wc_order_list_custom_column_content', 20, 2 );

I am not sure what you mean by "change this code and shows authors name not the orders id". Your current code should already retrieve and display the author’s name based on the customer ID associated with the order, else it will display "Unknown Author". For guest purchases the get_customer_id() method will return 0 (no user data) and the code will display “Unknown Author”.

Your question is not clear. Now when orders are passed via checkout, the author is somehow the customer, and you already get the customer first and last name displayed in the 1st column on admin orders. So what are you trying to do?

There are mainly 3 cases for WooCommerce order creation (related to the order author):
1). Orders placed via checkout:
When an order is placed via checkout, it's always created by the customer (billing first name and last name) for both Guests and registered users.
You already get this information via the first column from admin orders list.

And you can see on "Origin" column "Direct".
Note that when HPOS is not enabled or enabled with compatibility mode, the "post_author" is set to 0.
2). Orders created manually via the admin:
In this case, the author is the authorized user (administrator or shop manager) that creates the order.
From admin orders list, on "Origin" column, you will see "Web admin".
If HPOS is enabled without compatibility mode, the author information is only partially available via the order admin notes, where you can get somehow the author display name and email (but it's not reliable).
If HPOS is enabled with compatibility mode, you can get the author ID from the WC_Order object like:
$author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $order->get_id() );

3). Orders created Programmatically:
Here, the origin and author information is only available if it's set via the code.

You can use the WC_Order property "created_via" using get_created_via() method to see how the order has been created. The known displayed values are:

"checkout" for orders placed via checkout (1),
"admin" for orders created manually via the backend (2).

When creating an order programmatically (3), you can define "created_via" using set_created_via() method.

For orders created manually when HPOS is enabled (without compatibility mode), you can save the author ID using the following:
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'set_author_id_on_manual_orders', 40 );
function set_author_id_on_manual_orders( $order_id ) {
    global $current_user;

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id); // Get WC_Order object instance
    
    //check if author ID exist
    if ( ! $order->get_meta('author_id') && ! $order->is_created_via('checkout') ) {

        $order->update_meta_data( 'author_id', $current_user->ID );
        $order->save();
    }
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin).
Then to get the author ID use $author_id = $order->get_meta('author_id');

thanks for your help. actually I want to have a column that shows which one of my admins ( shop managers ) created an order. ( it's very helpful to finding and managing admins and tracking orders. that's what I want. Before Enabling HPOS I can use Legacy codes and etc but after Enabling HPOS I can't. I want from you if it possible write a function that Create a custom column in my WooCommerce Orders page that Show who created an order manually.

@AmirmohammadMohammadi I added some code at the end of my answer, to save the author ID, for orders created manually when HPOS is enabled (without compatibility mode). This way you can get easily the author ID.

Thanks sir. if I want to show the author's name, wich field id should I use?
